# How to show underscore (shortcut) without holding Alt?

Tags: c#, .net, shortcut, contextmenustrip

I've created a form with ContextMenuStrip. I set its shortcut using Text field in following way: "&File". However, when I open this context menu by right mouse button click, underscore is shown only when I simultaneously hold Alt button. Is there a way to show underscore on a mouse click without holding Alt button?

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163617/is-there-a-way-to-force-always-show-mnemonics-in-menus

Comment: I am not sure, that is why I am asking :) Maybe there is some sort a workaround, to show it not depending on setting?

Comment: Yes, it is a user preference, you should not ignore it.  Control Panel > Ease of Access Center > Make the keyboard easier to use > Underline keyboard shortcuts and access keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the text rendering behaviour (`HidePrefix`) via a custom `ToolStripSystemRenderer`:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            contextMenuStrip1.Renderer = new AccessKeyMenuStripRenderer();
        }

        private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);
        }
    }

    class AccessKeyMenuStripRenderer : ToolStripSystemRenderer 
    {
        protected override void OnRenderItemText(ToolStripItemTextRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            e.TextFormat &= ~TextFormatFlags.HidePrefix;
            base.OnRenderItemText(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, that is exactly what I need! Could you please tell me, where can I read more about Renderer?

Comment: See the "How To" links at the bottom of: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.renderer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx