# Make a context menu on a NotifyIcon ALWAYS show hotkey underscore

Tags: vb.net, contextmenu, hotkeys, notifyicon

I appreciate that when asking for help on this forum, the etiquette is to show what you've tried to do and then explain what's not working; instead of just asking "how do you do XYZ" - but this question is a bit of the latter ... so not sure if this question will get closed, before anyone suggest an answer ?!

I have VB.NET Winforms application has a ToolStripMenuItem with various options on it and some of them have an ampersand before their titles, so that they will appear as hotkeys when the user presses the ALT key.  These work as expected.

I also have a NotifyIcon on the form, with an associated contextMenuStrip and again options on that menu and some set-up as HotKeys (eg &Exit ).  But the hotkeys on the NotifyIcon do not appear and obviously if the user clicks the ALT key, then the menu disappears. The hotkeys do work, but the user needs to know what they are, because they don't see the underscore character.

Now on my PC, I have about a dozen programs in the system tray, such as Outlook etc and non of them show the underscore character under any of their menu options - so that gave me the idea that it wasn't possible .... BUT the icon for Skype Business; does show the underscores (irrespective of pressing the ALT key), so I was wondering if anyone knew how Microsoft accomplished that ?

Cheers,

Chris.

Comment: The underscore (called _mnemonics_) can be forced to be drawn by overriding the default renderer for the `ContextMenuStrip`. See this answer (easily convertable to VB.NET using an online converter): http://stackoverflow.com/a/29800409/3740093

Comment: Brilliant - that's done the trick.  Many thanks !!