# Mnemonics won't show up in a SWT window

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, mnemonics

I have been trying to set up mnemonics on my buttons in a SWT window (Eclipse plugin), but unfortunately I always end up with the following cases:

1. Either I use `setText("&Cancel")`: it doesn't show the mnemonics until you press the "alt" button
2. Or I use `setText("&&Cancel")`, but the button looks like "&Cancel". This "double ampersand" trick was found on the Eclipse forum.

If you already faced the problem, I would be glad to read your solutions to fix this. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Well, isn't that how mnemonics are supposed to work? Don't show them until the user presses `Alt` ? On Windows you have to force-enable the underlining of mnemonics (cf http://stackoverflow.com/a/10164042) to make them show all the time.

Comment: Indeed, it seems like you are right. Then do you know how to programmatically force the underlining of the mnemonic character ?  (For instance, Eclipse menus has the mnemonics showing up even if you don't press the Alt key)

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to find a solution. Here is how to simulate a ALT keystroke:

```
private void showMnemonics() {

    Event event = new Event();
    event.keyCode = SWT.ALT;
    event.type = SWT.KeyDown;
    Display.getDefault().post(event);

}
```

Edit : I guess the following code should be add to the method, in order to release the key :

```
event.type = SWT.KeyUp;
Display.getDefault().post(event);
```